# Using javascript to analyse contrast of image

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing

I'm wondering if it is possible to analyse an image from an api call to find out if the image has a high or low level of contrast. I know there is [resemble.js](http://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/) which finds the differences between two images. So I think what I want to do is possible.

How would I go about analyzing the contrast level of an image? If it's not possible in javascript, what solutions are there in other languages?

Comment: Use getImageData and from there standard image algorithms.

Comment: on the image data, i guess you can compare Math.max.apply(0,imgData) against Math.min.apply(0, imgData), but that's only going to tell you the total contrast, not the average contrast. if i had a 1000X1000 grid with all pixels set to 128 save two, at 10 and 245, can you really claim the image has 240 level of contrast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most solutions are based on

1. the fetching of the image
2. the creation of an in memory canvas
3. the drawing of the image onto the canvas using `drawImage`
4. the recuperation of the pixel data using `getImageData`. You get an array where every pixels is defined by the sequence of four numbers (RGBA)
5. the application of any algorithm on those pixels. There are many algorithms for the determination of contrast, each one with strengths and weakness, you'll have to choose the one that fits your needs

Exemple for the first steps (the last one being dependent on your needs) :

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = myImage.width;
canvas.height = myImage.height;
var context = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);
var pixels = context.getImageData(0, 0, myImage.width, myImage.height).data;
```

Comment: This is just a HTML5 canvas setup; nowhere does it deal with contrast or answers the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Pixastic is a JavaScript library which allows you to perform a variety of operations, filters and fancy effects on images using just a bit of JavaScript.
It works by utilizing HTML5 Canvas element

After loading an image,

```
params.options.contrast
```

gives you the value of contrast.

More information and demo is available [here](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/brightness/)

Comment: Hi, I might be wrong but it seems like pixastic sets contrast to a standard value of 0.5 then uses that to alter the contrast from there. But I'm really just after that initial contrast value so that it can be compared to other images

Comment: Hi. The link is out of date maybe you can check this: http://dph.am/pixastic-docs/